# default netmask in Solaris

Tags: networking, solaris, ifconfig

On a Solaris local zone, what is the default netmask?

I have a blank `/etc/netmasks` file, but if I run `ifconfig` I can see that the  netmask is set to `ffffff00` .

```
[username@servername]# /usr/sbin/ifconfig -a
lo0:10: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
ifname5:3: flags=1000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 7
        inet 10.56.20.179 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.56.20.255
```

How is the subnet mask set on a reboot if the `netmasks` file is blank? 
Is this based on something in the global zone?

Similarly (??), where is the default subnet mask set if the `ifconfig` command is used to set the address for an interface and the netmask is not explicitly set in the command?

**clarification** I want to check the  configured subnet mask for non-global zones based on static configuration files, for purpose of predicting behavior on reboot or failover. What file(s) has this information?

As schilly mentioned, the example I gave is probably not typical setup for 10.x.x.x network, but I think someone (more experienced than  me) configured its settings on purpose and I am trying to make inventory of the network settings for all the non-global zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the zone and the solaris version you might have to specify the network in different ways.
Using shared network interface, the zone OS does not need to know about the network configuration because this is shared with the global zone. So in fact you networks will be defined in the global zone and you just specify the IP in the zonecfg configuration.

If you are using exclusive-IP (available on Solaris 11), then you need to configure manually the ip inside each zone as they have separate IP stack.

schily mentioned and quite well, that if a network mask is not specify it is taken from the defaults. If you look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/6mbb1kq31/) you will find the following:

netmask mask

```
For IPv4 only. Specify how much of the address to reserve for subdividing networks into subnetworks. The mask includes the network part of the local address and the subnet part, which is taken from the host field of the address. The mask contains 1's for the bit positions in the 32-bit address which are to be used for the network and subnet parts, and 0's for the host part. The mask should contain at least the standard network portion, and the subnet field should be contiguous with the network portion. The mask can be specified in one of four ways:

    with a single hexadecimal number with a leading 0x,

    with a dot-notation address,

    with a “+” (plus sign) address, or

    with a pseudo host name/pseudo network name found in the network database networks(4).

If a “+” (plus sign) is given for the netmask value, the mask is looked up in the netmasks(4) database. This lookup finds the longest matching netmask in the database by starting with the interface's IPv4 address as the key and iteratively masking off more and more low order bits of the address. This iterative lookup ensures that the netmasks(4) database can be used to specify the netmasks when variable length subnetmasks are used within a network number.

If a pseudo host name/pseudo network name is supplied as the netmask value, netmask data may be located in the hosts or networks database. Names are looked up by first using gethostbyname(3NSL). If not found there, the names are looked up in getnetbyname(3SOCKET). These interfaces may in turn use nsswitch.conf(4) to determine what data store(s) to use to fetch the actual value.

For both inet and inet6, the same information conveyed by mask can be specified as a prefix_length attached to the address parameter.
```

Additionally,
If you are using shared address in the zone configuration and you configure an ip that is not recognized via zonecfg you will see the following message:

```
zone 'zone-shared-ip': warning: net0: no matching subnet found in netmasks(4): 10.0.2.150; using default of 255.0.0.0
```

Comment: Crossbow (and thus fully separated IP) is available in all OpenSolaris development releases starting from 2005.

Comment: "networks will be defined in the global zone" . does this mean default subnet masks for non-global zones are defined in the /etc/netmasks in the global zone?

Comment: see my updated answer for clarification shared address zones

Answer (score 0):

As usual in UNIX, the netmask is set to the default that matches the address range.

`127.0.0.1` is e.g. a class A address and thus gets a netmask of 255.255.255.0

The other network in your example seems to have been set up with e local configuration specific value.

Comment: any reference for this?

Comment: Did you read the man page? If you do not specify a mask, the network needs to follow the standard behavior by default. This is routing based on the address classes.

Comment: I read the man page for netmasks and ifconfig but didn't find info about default netmask or network classes in them. Am I looking at the wrong man pages? It looks like zonecfg is maybe relevant, I will check that.

Comment: Well, as there is no special information, it needs to follow the rules for the network address classes by default.